# can currencyconverter ignore the $ sign when not entered

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, converters

In a datatable, I have to validate the input as currency. When I enter the value after deleting the $ sign, the input component throws an error.

```
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel value="REC REVENUE" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:inputText id="RERVN" styleClass="RERVN"
       value="#{segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['RERVN'].segmentValues[rank].rangeMinValue}"
   disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['RERVN'].selected  ||    (rank==fn:length(segmentSetup.ranks)) }"
validator="#{segmentSetup.validateRanges}">
            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="0" currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="RERVN" />
    </p:column>
```

When I enter a value without the dollar sign, I get this validation error.

#### tabView:segmentRangeTable:0:GRRVN: '45' could not be understood as a currency value. Example: $99.99

Comment: I posted an Issue at https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1324

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `$` apart from the input and use a normal number converter.

```html
$<p:inputText ...>
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="0" />
</p:inputText>
```

You can if necessary use CSS to reposition the $ visually back into the input element. Here's a kickoff example in plain HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="currency"><span>$</span><input /></div>
```

with

```css
.currency span { position: absolute; margin: 5px 2px; }
.currency input { padding-left: 5px; }
```

Comment: can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345523/selectbooleancheckbox-in-datatable-header-not-calling-actionlistener