# selectBooleanCheckBox in datatable header not calling actionListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable with three columns and a checkboxes in the header of each column. When I select one checkbox, I have to update the other 2 check boxes. Each row under these columns is an input box with a validator. When I submit the form, I can see the validators executing but my actionListener is not invoked. There is no stack trace as well. Please suggest.

```
    <p:dataTable id="segmentRangeTable" var="rank"
    value="#{segmentSetup.ranks}">

    <p:column headerText="Segment Names">
        <p:outputPanel layout="block">
            <p:inputText id="segmentName" style="text-transform:uppercase"
                value="#{segmentSetup.userSegment.segmentNames[rank].name}"
                validator="#{segmentSetup.validateNames}" immediate="true" />
            <p:message for="segmentName" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel layout="block">
                <p:outputLabel value="AUM" />
                <br />

                <p:outputPanel id="AUMcheckBox">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="Default Rating" 
                        styleClass="defaultRating"
                        value="#{segmentSetup.defaultRating eq 'AUM' ? true : false}"
                        disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['AUM'].selected}" >
                        <p:ajax update=":tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REREVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:AUMcheckBox" process="@this" immediate="true"
                            listener="#{segmentSetup.changeDefaultRating('AUM')}" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                </p:outputPanel>

            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
        <p:inputText id="AUM" styleClass="AUM"
            value="#{segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['AUM'].segmentValues[rank].rangeMinValue}"
            disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['AUM'].selected || (rank==fn:length(segmentSetup.ranks))}"
            validator="#{segmentSetup.validateRanges}" immediate="true" >
            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" currencySymbol="$"
                type="currency" minFractionDigits="0" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="AUM" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputLabel value="GROSS REVENUE" />
                <br />
                <p:outputPanel id="REVcheckBox">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="Default Rating" 
                        styleClass="defaultRating"
                        value="#{segmentSetup.defaultRating eq 'GRRVN' ? true : false}"
                        disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['GRRVN'].selected}">
                        <p:ajax update=":tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REREVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:AUMcheckBox" immediate="true"
                            listener="#{segmentSetup.changeDefaultRating('GRRVN')}">
                        </p:ajax>
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:inputText id="GRRVN" styleClass="GRRVN"
                value="#{segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['GRRVN'].segmentValues[rank].rangeMinValue}"
                disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['GRRVN'].selected  || (rank==fn:length(segmentSetup.ranks)) }"
                validator="#{segmentSetup.validateRanges}" immediate="true" >
                <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" currencySymbol="$"
                    type="currency" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="GRRVN" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputLabel value="REC REVENUE" />

                <br />
                <p:outputPanel id="REREVcheckBox">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="Default Rating" 
                        styleClass="defaultRating"
                        value="#{segmentSetup.defaultRating eq 'RERVN' ? true : false}"
                        disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['RERVN'].selected}">
                        <p:ajax update=":tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REREVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:REVcheckBox :tabView:clientSegmentationTabForm:segmentRangeTable:AUMcheckBox" immediate="true"
                            listener="#{segmentSetup.changeDefaultRating('RERVN')}">
                        </p:ajax>
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:outputPanel>

            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>

        <p:inputText id="RERVN" styleClass="RERVN"
            value="#{segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['RERVN'].segmentValues[rank].rangeMinValue}"
            disabled="#{!segmentSetup.userSegmentTypesMap['RERVN'].selected  || (rank==fn:length(segmentSetup.ranks)) }"
            validator="#{segmentSetup.validateRanges}" >
            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="0"
                currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:message for="RERVN" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<p:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="blx-align-rl">
    <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" process="@form"
        update="@form" actionListener="#{segmentSetup.save}" >
        <f:param name="VALIDATE" value="true" />
        </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" update="@form"
        actionListener="#{segmentSetup.reset}" immediate="true" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I think you have to specify an `event` for your `<p:ajax/>` to have the listener called. Try with `onclick` or `onchange`.

Comment: I am able to get to the Listener. The action listener on my save button is not invoked.

Comment: Can you add code for save method (at least signature)?

Comment: Try with `action` in order of `actionListener`.

Comment: @Smith, which is it? Your selectCheckBox actionListener or your saveButton? Your question and comment don't match. If your lifecycle processing couldn't make it past the validation phase, it's probably likely the reason is simply that one of your components failed validations. `actionListener`s silently fail like that without propagating exceptions to the top and as a result are not advisable for actual business logic. You could either switch to `action` and watch for problems,inspect your browser's console or put `<h:messages/>` to observe errors

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem trying to use the select state to render or not render another panel. I am using basically JSF 2 and Richfaces.
Finally what worked for me was use the "onchange" from the component and call a little js that changed my panel property for "none" and as "important".

It looked almost like this:

```
 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
    id="idCheck"
    value="#{bean.hidePanel}"
    onchange="changePanelView()">
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

And the js:

```
    <script>
        function changePanelView() {
            if (document.getElementById('idForm:idCheck').checked) {
                document.getElementById('idPanel').style.setProperty('display', '', 'important');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('idPanel').style.setProperty(
'display','none', 'important');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This page already use some ajax tricks but for I removed from this situation because it was re-rendering the panel, overwrinting the property "display"