# JSF Default currency (Autofill $ on tabout)

Tags: jsf, input, converters, currency

Currently the JSF throws a conversion error if `<f:convertNumber type="currency"/>` is used and the user inputs a value of `1.99` instead of `$1.99`.

How to make the `1.99` value is considered as `$1.99` without writing a custom converter?

Comment: if f:convertNumber is used..

Comment: possible duplicate of [can currencyconverter ignore the $ sign when not entered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344144/can-currencyconverter-ignore-the-sign-when-not-entered)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it is a problem, to write a custom converter to auto-attach a "$". But if you don't do it, your only other option is to do it via javascript. Something like this:

```
onblur="$('#input-field-id').val('$' + $('#input-field-id').val())"
```

Comment: If you're not sure because you can't test yet, don't post it as answer then.

Comment: Sorry about that, I checked it now and it really didn't work. I honestly didn't expect that and wanted to give him a fast feedback. I removed that part.